# Streaming data to web browser using play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-cluster

I'd like a guidance or any clue about how to stream data from a message broker server to any user who would like to access that streaming.

This streaming is based on json data. I'm using the scala's play framework.

What should I consider to use? Akka? Publish subscribe pattern? Should I use websockets?

I'm struggling to find a solution, althought I'm still getting familiar with the docs from play community. Any help or clue is really welcome.

I had asked before about this scenario at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076584/streaming-jsons-objects-from-apache-spark-streaming-to-play-framework but I haven't gotten any answer so far.

Comment: What message broker?

Comment: When it comes to streaming to browsers - only real option is `WebSockets` nothing else. Though you can consider comet as an option.

Comment: @m-z I'm using the apache Kafka as I'm integrating my project with apache spark streaming